# Parse Geocodio::Address

Tags: json, ruby, parsing, geocode

I'm using ruby and the geocodio gem to do some reverse geocoding.  The reverse geocoder returns an object of type  Geocodio::Address which per their website is JSON.  I'm trying to use ruby JSON:parse to convert to a hash that I can them map as needed.

JSON parse returns this error...

C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse': 784: unexpected token at '"Saipan, MP 96950"' (J
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/json/common.rb:156:in`parse'

Here's my whole script

```
        require 'geocodio'
    require 'CSV'
    require 'json'

    filename = './for_fips.csv'
    #fipslist = []
    geocodio = Geocodio::Client.new('not real...d5a1557e2175d8ce265')
    i = 1
    CSV.foreach(filename) do |row|
      lat = row[1]
      long = row[2]
      coord = lat + "," + long
      #puts coord
      add = geocodio.reverse_geocode([lat + "," + long],fields: %w[cd stateleg school timezone]).best
      add_parsed = JSON.parse(add)
      pp add_parsed
      #puts add.each { |k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join('~~')
      i +=1
      if i > 2 then break end
      #fipslist << fcc.district_fips
    end
```

Comment: Your code looks ok, but it's impossible to figure out what is blowing up the `JSON.parse` without seeing the actual JSON. What does the `add` variable contain?

Comment: You probably should remove your API key from the code sample.  :)

Comment: You could use the GeoIPCountry CSV file, instead [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WhitewidowScanner/whitewidow/master/lib/lists/GeoIPCountry.csv)

Comment: Be sure that the `add` variable is a `String`, if it's meant to be parsable JSON. If `add` is a `Hash` that won't parse as JSON.